# Mapping nested data from additional information in email notification

Tags: json, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, nested-json

Suppose i had sent nested json data in additional information in em_alert, how do i access the nested data in the Email notification?

For example the additional info  has below nested value, how do i access data1 and data2  fields in the Email notification?

{data1:value1,data2:value2}

[image]